# Trying to filter an array of products with an array of filters upon click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter a list of products depending on the selected filters by the user. For example:

Here is the list of products:

```
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        productName: 'Strawberry Basil',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373',
        type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'],
        price: 5.5,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        productName: 'Sour Blueberry',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584',
        type: ['sour', 'berry'],
        price: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        productName: 'Blackberry Jam',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965',
        type: ['berry'],
        price: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        productName: 'Orange Nectarine',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Orange_Nectarine_Still_4K_Front-OrangeNectarine.png?v=1588713522',
        type: ['citrus', 'fancy', 'juicy'],
        price: 6,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        productName: 'Lemon Verbena',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Lemon_Verbena_Still_4K_Front-LemonVerbena.png?v=1588713474',
        type: ['citrus', 'classic', 'floral'],
        price: 4.5,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        productName: 'Extra Peach',
        productImgURL:
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/ExtraPeach_Still_4K_Front-ExtraPeach.png?v=1588713411',
        type: ['juicy'],
        price: 8.5,
    }
]
```

I'm grouping the filters upon user's click like this:

```
const filtered = ['classy', 'berries', 'juicy']
```

How can I filter the product list to show all those products that have this type in their types of array property? So if the user clicks on one then it will filter one and so on.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried `.filter()`, `.some()`, things like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to find the products that match the filtered Array.

For each product we check if the product.type array and filtered array overlap:

```js
const products = [ { id: 1, productName: 'Strawberry Basil', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373', type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'], price: 5.5, }, { id: 2, productName: 'Sour Blueberry', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584', type: ['sour', 'berry'], price: 4, }, { id: 3, productName: 'Blackberry Jam', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965', type: ['berry'], price: 10, }, { id: 4, productName: 'Orange Nectarine', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Orange_Nectarine_Still_4K_Front-OrangeNectarine.png?v=1588713522', type: ['citrus', 'fancy', 'juicy'], price: 6, }, { id: 5, productName: 'Lemon Verbena', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Lemon_Verbena_Still_4K_Front-LemonVerbena.png?v=1588713474', type: ['citrus', 'classic', 'floral'], price: 4.5, }, { id: 6, productName: 'Extra Peach', productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/ExtraPeach_Still_4K_Front-ExtraPeach.png?v=1588713411', type: ['juicy'], price: 8.5, } ]
const filtered = ['classy', 'berries', 'juicy'];

const results = products.filter(product => { 
    return product.type.some(productType => filtered.includes(productType))
})

console.log(`Matching products (${results.length}):`, results.map( ({ productName }) => productName));
```